# Centripetal acceleration and tangential velocity for object that rotate and revolve in same time?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

Right picture is two turn tables on of top of the other, smaller turn table is connected with shaft to bigger one so it rotate around itself and in same time "revolve" around center of bigger one which is also rotate about itself. They both rotate clockwise.  ω1 = 2 x  ω2

I observe case from inertial frame of reference, earth.
I must find centripetal acceleration $(ac)$ and tangential velocity $(vt)$ in point B.

$$v t = ω r$$

$$ac = ω^2r$$

$$ac(B)=(ω_2)^2r_2+(ω_1)^2r_1(A)$$

$$vt(B)=ω_2r_2+ω_1r_1(A)$$

Is this correct?

(Point A show case where smaller turn table rotate just around itself, revolution is zero)

[image]

Comment: Accelerations and velocities are vectors and can be added as vectors. In other words, find the velocity of B relative to P1, then add this (as a vector) to the velocity of P1 relative to P2.

Comment: for v from b relativ toP2 you should use r1+r2 so v=575m/s, and again r1+r2 for centripedal force, but only for B at the place you marked .

Comment: I do not understand your comment, in the moment B is at the place you draw it its distance to P2 is r1+r2, half a rotation of the small table it is r2-r2 and the velocities are  in opposit direction. s the centripedal force ist dependend from the location of B